# Integral involving a Multi-Valued function

Tags: complex-integration, branch-cuts

I don't really have any idea about how does one calculate integrals involving Multi-valued functions, all I know about Multi - valued functions, are the closely associated concepts of Branch Points and Branch Cuts, about which almost the entirety of my knowledge can be summarised by THIS: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.04/Notes/Branch_Points_B_Cuts.pdf

SO, I understand the basic concept behind a multi valued function ( i.e. what makes it be ambiguously defined ), how to compute these branch points in most cases and understand that generally speaking branch cuts are curves that join two of these branch points, that's about it.

I do not have a working knowledge of how to integrate these functions into the grander whole of things, which is what this problem really expects me to have.

So, I just understand that the Branch points of this function are: +1,-1 and infinity and further that, when we consider an 'appropriate branch' of the $log(z^{2}-1)$ function, we will be able to apply the Residue theorem to solve this problem since this function, when unambiguously defined is Meromorphic, but how do I go about using that knowledge to define 'branches' of this function is the step that I really require an explanation for.

[image: The Problem :]

Comment: Can you see that the ingrand (whatever branch of it is chosen, assuming *it is really a branch*, that is, it is at least continuous) is analytic on $C$ and *inside of it*? (If you do, the answer is immediate.)

Comment: Umm, would it have anything to do with the fact that C ( the ellipse ) doesn’t enclose any of the branch points of the function? ( the ellipse sits there with its major axis along the Real axis, which extends from [-1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)] hence not enclosing the branch point (1,-1) )

Comment: Exactly. (And the poles $z=\pm i$ of $1/(z^2+1)$ are also outside.)

Comment: Okay, so since we don’t have any singular points ( Poles ) lying inside the curve, they do not contribute to our integrand’s value via the residue of the function at those points, and hence by Cauchy‘s theorem since the function is holomorphic, this integral evaluates to zero? If that’s correct I still want to ask what is really meant by considering a ‘branch’ of the $log(z^{2}-1)$ function.